# How to Process multiple files in talend one after another and the size of the files are too large?

Tags: talend

i want to process the multiple files using talend and one after another and the size of the files are large and while processing one file if another file comes into that directory it has to process that file also.
is there any possible way to do this could you please suggest guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tFileList** component, which will *iterate all the files in a given directory.*

You can check the component functionality [here](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tFileList)

Simple concept would be,

- When there is a file in a directory say Folder1, move that file to another location say Folder2.
- After processing file in Folder2 again, check Folder1, that is any new files arrived.
- If arrived, then again move that file to Folder2 and process it.
- If there is no new file, end the job.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do this in Talend is to setup a file watcher job which is simple to do.  Talend provides the tWaitForFile Component which will watch a directory for files.  You can configure the max iterations in which it will look for the file and time between polls/scans.  Since you said you are loading large files, to avoid DB concurrency issues give enough time between scans to account for this.

In my example below I am watching a directory for new files, scanning every 60 seconds over an 8 hour period.  You would want to schedule the job in either the TAC or whatever scheduling tool you use.  In my example I simply join to a tJavaRow and display the information about the file that was found.

[image]

you can see the output from my tJavaRow here which shows the file info:

[image]